# AngularJS how to compare similar objects in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I currently want to make a system that can compare products and their prices and list them.

I have found a way to filter duplicate products in AngularJS using the unique filter of AngularUI. I have two JSON files each filled with products of two different providers.

But I don't want it to remove the duplicate I want to get back a list of the similar products so someone can compare the prices and choose his favorite provider of the product.

If I run a ng-repeat with the unique filter it simply removes a duplicate. Is there a compare filter?

Comment: At some time, you'll have to write some code by yourself. And define what "similar" and "compare" means precisely.

Comment: Try Writing a custom filter  :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what you want, you'd need to write a custom filter that does the comparison and determines whether two objects are similar by your definition.  Something like this.  Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/NxFtPy?p=preview):

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
  .filter('similar', function() {
    return function(input, comparedObject) {
      console.log(comparedObject);
      var newArray = [];
      for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i].itemType === comparedObject.itemType) {
          newArray.push(input[i]);
        }
      }
      return newArray;
    }
  });

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.baseObject = {
    name: 'fred',
    itemType: 1
  };
  $scope.castList = [
    {
      name: 'wilma',
      itemType: 2
    }, 
    {
      name: 'bam-bam',
      itemType: 1
    }, 
    {
      name: 'barney',
      itemType: 1
    }, 
    {
      name: 'dino',
      itemType: 3
    }
  ];
});
```

Then you would need something like this in the view's HTML.

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="SomeCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="person in castList | similar : baseObject">
            <p>{{person.name}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Notice that the "baseObject" referred to in the filter in the view is defined in the scope from the controller.

This custom filter compares based upon the object's "itemType" property, which in my example is just a number.  You'd have to re-write the filter to compare based on what you want.  So what you get here is a display of only those objects that have an itemType property of 1, which is the same as the baseObject's.